# Access external endpoints based on istio ServiceEntry name?

Tags: kubernetes, external, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-operator

I am currently checking whether we can able to connect the external endpoint based on the serviceentry name to allow us to easily switch the hosts configured in the serviceentry. Below is the current config I am using and also enabled `ISTIO_META_DNS_CAPTURE: "true"` in the istio config

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-cluster-dev
spec:
  exportTo:
  - .
  hosts:
  - dev-elastic.es.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: https
    number: 443
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: DNS
```

But the connection request to elasticsearch-cluster-dev returns  `Could not resolve host`

```
root@nginx:/# curl https://elasticsearch-cluster-dev
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: elasticsearch-cluster-dev
root@nginx:/#
```

Can we able to connect to an external endpoint based on the ServiceEntry name in istio? Am i missing any istio config?

Comment: Do you have any DestinationRules or VirtualServices deployed?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceEntry name is just a meta information for Istio. It does not signify any host information. You should be using the host url instead. From what I can tell, the name based switching is not possible

```
curl https://dev-elastic.es.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io
```